# Movement analysis - trying to calculate mean speed/ step length per day but keep getting NAs?

Tags: r, spatial, na, latitude-longitude

I'm analyzing animal movement data to look for differences in movement patterns between three periods using lat and long co-ordinates. I want to calculate mean speed and step length per day. I have pre-processed my data and attributed the correct time zone (POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC", +proj=utm +zone=34S +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs".

Here is a sample of my processed data:

```
Longitude Latitude          DateTime   Herd   ID        X       Y
1 -34.03991 23.27494 2020-03-25 08:30:00 During DUR1 -5751275 4096741
2 -34.03991 23.27494 2020-03-25 08:35:00 During DUR1 -5751275 4096741
3 -34.03991 23.27494 2020-03-25 08:40:00 During DUR1 -5751275 4096741
4 -34.03991 23.27494 2020-03-25 08:45:00 During DUR1 -5751275 4096741
5 -34.03991 23.27494 2020-03-25 08:50:00 During DUR1 -5751275 4096741
6 -34.03991 23.27494 2020-03-25 08:55:00 During DUR1 -5751275 4096741
```

I have calculated the daily means using this code:

```
caribou <- mutate(caribou, Year = year(Time), Month = month(Time), DOY = yday(Time))
caribou.daily <- ddply(caribou, c("ID", "Year", "DOY", "Herd", "nickname"),  summarize, Latitude = mean(Latitude), Longitude = mean(Longitude), X = mean(X),                        Y = mean(Y))

caribou.daily <- mutate(caribou.daily, Date = ymd(paste(Year - 1, 12, 31)) + 
                          ddays(DOY), Month = month(Date))
attr(caribou.daily, "projection") <- attr(caribou, "projection")
```

Sample of daily data:

```
ID Year DOY   Herd nickname Latitude Longitude        X       Y
1  DUR1 2020  85 During    DUR.1 23.27242 -34.03806 -5751234 4096230
2 DUR10 2020  98 During    DUR.2 23.27053 -34.03508 -5750989 4095724
3 DUR11 2020  99 During    DUR.3 23.27584 -34.03885 -5751055 4096792
4 DUR12 2020 100 During    DUR.4 23.27597 -34.03830 -5750970 4096768
5 DUR13 2020 105 During    DUR.5 23.26958 -34.03506 -5751065 4095583
6 DUR14 2020 106 During    DUR.6 23.27366 -34.03502 -5750719 4096178
```

And am now trying to calculate the daily speed and step length using the following code:

```
computeDD <- function(data) {
  Z <- data$X + (0+1i) * data$Y
  StepLength <- c(NA, Mod(diff(Z)))
  dT <- c(NA, as.numeric(diff(data$Date)))
  Speed <- StepLength/dT
  return(data.frame(data, StepLength, dT, Speed))
}

caribou.daily <- ddply(caribou.daily, "ID", computeDD)
caribou.daily
```

However, this code only produces NAs for the variables I'm trying to create.

Please could someone advise on what I might be doing wrong? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: You need to edit your question and include example data so that we can run your code. That is, not just show some data, but add code that generates it, just like in the R help files.